# What is the 'law' in John 19:7

Tags: john, law, judaism

In John 19:7 it says,

> 7 The Jews answered him, “We have a law, and according to that law he ought to die because he has made himself the Son of God.”

What is the law that they are speaking of here? Is it in the Old Testament, or is it from Jewish tradition or elsewhere?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it speaks about Deuteronomy 13.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Commentators generally see this as a reference to the Mosaic laws forbidding blasphemy. For example, *[Barnes' Notes](http://biblehub.com/commentaries/barnes/john/19.htm)*, the *[Pulpit Commentary](http://biblehub.com/commentaries/pulpit/john/19.htm)*, the *[Cambridge Bible](http://biblehub.com/commentaries/cambridge/john/19.htm)* and *[Ellicott's Commentary](http://biblehub.com/commentaries/ellicott/john/19.htm)* see it this way.

> Whoever blasphemes the name of the LORD shall surely be put to death. All the congregation shall stone him. The sojourner as well as the native, when he blasphemes the Name, shall be put to death.  (Leviticus 24:16, ESV)

However, [Matthew Poole](http://biblehub.com/commentaries/poole/john/19.htm) sees it as a reference to Deuteronomy 18:20 allowing false prophets to be executed:

> But the prophet who presumes to speak a word in my name that I have not commanded him to speak, or who speaks in the name of other gods, that same prophet shall die. (ESV)

Comment: You could add in [Bernard's ICC](https://goo.gl/cuX1PN) and [Dods in the Expositors Greek Testament](https://goo.gl/oy3IZH) for the Lev 24:16 identification. It continues among modern commentators, too (R.E. Brown, vol. 2, p. 877; Leon Morris, p. 795; Barnabas Lindars, p. 567) often in relation to [John 10:33ff](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John+10%3A33-34&version=NIV).

Comment: @ThaddeusB, thanks for your clear and helpful answer. What you wrote explains it exactly.

Answer (score 0):

**Sons ye [are] to Jehovah your God**; Deut 14:1

it is necessary to take into account the articulateand complex sociological framework of Jesus' time in relation to "foreigners". The Old Testament (AT) uses the terms zar (the alien in the ethnic and political sense with a derogatory connotation) and nekar (the one that belongs to an ethnic group from which Israel must separate); as for foreigners present in Israel, the TA distinguishes nokri,the temporary resident, and gher,the immigrant, the resident foreigner, the one who lives in the midst of a people with which he has no blood relations. The New Testament (NT) attests to the presence of proselylls (Mt 23:15: foreigners who converted and accepted the Torah and circumcision), worshippers of God (Acts 18:7: people of pagan origin who professed monotheistic faith, attended the synagogue, but did not become fully members of the Jewish community) and Samaritans (cf. Jn 4). The latter, who are openly considered foreigners in Lk 17:18, where a Samaritan is called Alloghenés (a term that in the LXX translates the Hebrew zar), that is, of "other ethnicity", "foreign", historically were in an intermediate situation between Israel and foreigners: "the Samaritans were never treated purely and simply as foreigners, but as a group of dubious descent. Its Israeli origin cannot be considered as certain, but also cannot be discarded a priori. His membership of the Community of Israel is therefore not denied, but only considered dubious" (Emil Schürer). For these reasons, the situation in Jesus' time is such that "it makes it not pertinent to use a formal sociological definition and clear distinctions that lead to a univocal determination of who is the foreigner in Jewish society of the first century" (text of Ermenegildo Manicardi).

*The Jews answered and said unto him, Say we not well that thou art **a Samaritan**, and hast a devil?*  English Revised Version Jn 8:48

Jesus was not accepted among the sons of God, the Jews:

**a Samaritan** refers to the dubious fatherhood of Jesus before the Nazarene community.

Answer (score 0):

I would say these are hellenized Jews in John 19:7 who do not understand the Jewish term son of God. They understand the Roman/Greek term son of God which means a claim of divinity. Because if you look at john 8 other Jews made the exact same claim that they are accusing Jesus of making which he should be stoned for. According to the logic of John 19:7 these other Jews in John 8 ought to die as well. So I think John 19:7 are hellenized Jews who have adopted Roman/Greek culture.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).